# Package distributor has shipped an updated version - how to say yes after no

Tags: package-management, upgrade, updates, dpkg

After `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` I stepped into the:
*"Package distributor has shipped an updated version."*

Initially, I said no thinking this was the safest option.
Unfortunately, now I have some processes broken and I think this can be the reason.

Is there a way to revert my previous answer and say **Yes** even after I have previously said **No**?

This is the specific example: [image]

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know the name of the package? Check `/var/log/apt/term.log`. I'd try to reinstall the package `sudo apt reinstall <package>`. Generally more details are needed to give corrcet advice, we would need to see the original terminal output. Just imagine: you said no, to what???

Comment: The old (or new, depending on what you picked) config file will be saved next to the current config file, so you can use both contents as needed to make the final config file.